# Send JSON to PHP and get a response

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous

I'm just learning how to use jQuery and PHP together. This is my first attempt, and I feel like I'm almost getting the concept. However, there's an issue I failed to address. When I post a JSON object to PHP script and try to return one of the parameters, I get the following error : "Trying to get property of non-object in ..."

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <style id="jsbin-css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="postData();">Submit me!</button>
        <script>
            function postData() {
                var myData = {
                    'firstName' : 'John',
                    'lastName' : 'Doe'
                };   

                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "postData.php",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: myData,
                    success: function(msg){ 
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                         alert('error!' + err);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

postData.php:

```
<?php
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonData = json_decode($input);    
    $output = $jsonData->{'firstName'};
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving a json string on the server? You haven't told jquery to actually SEND json text, just to do a normal POST form submission. what does `var_dump($input)` look like?

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more work, you can achieve this using a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) client that will automatically handle data-type conversion and URL parsing among other things.

To name some of the advantages of using a REST architecture:

- Simple.
- You can easily scale your solution using caching, loading-balancing etc.
- Allows you to logically separate your URL-endpoints.
- It gives you the flexibility to change implementation easily without changing clients.

Try reading, [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) to get a better idea about the design pattern and it's uses. Of course you won't need to write a framework from scratch if you don't want to, since there are already several open-source PHP based implementations out there such as [Recess PHP Rest Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` (depending on PHP version) defaults to returning an array, not an object. The proper way to access it would be:

```
$output = $jsonData['firstname'];
```

You'll also want it to return an associative array, so pass `true` as the second argument of json_decode.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($input, true);
```

What could alternately be happening is that the JSON is invalid, in which case PHP returns `null`. You can check for that:

```
if ($jsonData = json_decode($input, true) === null) {
    // Do stuff!
} else {
    // Invalid JSON :(
}
```

Comment: I've changed code to this, yet it returns 'firstName is:' (Empty string unstead of actually firstName). I don't get that "Error with JSON format!" string, I get the 'correct' string, except, firstName is null. Very odd. Here's the code:
`<?php
 $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $output = '';
 if ($jsonData = json_decode($input, true) === null) {
     $output = 'firstName is: ' . $jsonData['firstname'];
 } else {
     $output = "Error with JSON format!";
 }
 echo $output;
?>`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Try running a `print_r($output)`  in the success block, and `echo ($input)` when you grab the input. Something is strange with the input.

Comment: When I did this: `$output = print_r($input);` the alert was as follows: `firstName=John&lastName=Doe1`
Why is there '1' in the string I have no idea.

Comment: print_r() does direct output, unless you force it to return its output instead (optional second argument). if you let it do output, it returns true/false for success/failure, which is why you have 1 there - it's the TRUE value returned by print_r

Comment: obviously then, I get passed this format `firstName=John&lastName=Doe`. Why can't I json_decode that?

Comment: Well, that's not json. Not sure why jQuery isn't working - that's not really my area of expertise - but you can decode that string with: `$params = explode('&', $input); foreach ($params as $p) { list($key, $value) = explode('=', $p); $jsonData[$key] = urldecode($value); }`

Answer (score 0):

I put it a little bit more simple with the function post of jquery.
I hope you found it useful:

first your html and js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style id="jsbin-css">
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button onClick="postData();">Submit me!</button>
      <script>
      function postData() {
        $.post(
            "postData.php",
            {
                firstName : 'John',
                lastName : 'Doe'
            },
            function(msg)
            {
                alert(msg);
            }
        );
      }

      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

then your php:

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['firstName']." - ".$_REQUEST['lastName'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

js:

```
function postData() {
var myData = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
};     

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "postData.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    success: function(msg){ 
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(err){
      alert('error!' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

php:

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonData = json_decode($input);
$output = $jsonData->{'firstName'};
echo $output;
?>
```

When decoding you DON'T want to put "true" as the second argument, because then, it's not JSON but an associative array (or so I've read). If I put json_decode($input, true), then it won't work.

Comment: Also, instead of putting JSON in javascript as 'firstName': 'John', it should be firstName: 'John' and then it should be used JSON.stringify which actually creates (a correct) JSON object.